# View in UITabBarController has 16 pixel buffer

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I have 5 tabs in a `UITabBarController` and all of them have a 16 pixel buffer around the edges in `InterfaceBuilder` and I can not figure out how to get rid of them without setting my constraints to `-16`. Here is what the buffer looks like in interface builder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

16px to the left plus 16px to the right is the standard margin.            You have to disable the "Constraint to margins" checkbox to remove this standard margin
[image: ConstraintoMarginScreenshot]

Comment: If you have already added constraints relative to the margins, just select the constraints and in the inspector uncheck "Relative to margin" in the popup for "First item" and "Second item"

Comment: Constraints to margin option is disabled.